# How can show all images with gallery view on semi circle

Tags: android

How can show all images with gallery view on semi circle and show all images on semi circle but as a wheel.when i click on semi circle image it will be show as a popup.

Comment: Be more specific..!! please add image that describes the way you want this..!!

Comment: I want to show all images on semi circle which will be fetch from server